# Why is the center of data important?

Tags: mean, descriptive-statistics, median, mode

I have recently begun learning statistics along with Python with the Anaconda IDE and started a Machine Learning course by Andrew Ng. I understand the mathematics behind what I am doing as the textbooks usually explain this part very well. However, whether it is the mean, median, mode, or any other technique used to find the center of data, I am wondering why we do this and what real-world results are after we apply it in a professional setting. Thank you.

Comment: Possibly of interest: [Should the mean be used when data are skewed?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96371/should-the-mean-be-used-when-data-are-skewed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it has nothing to do with being "in the center". In fact, those statistics can sometimes be far from what many people consider as "center", e.g. [for skewed distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203233/if-the-mean-and-median-underestimate-the-true-central-tendency-why-use-them/203251#203251). The point is rather that they provide a single-value summary of the distribution: mean is the value where [probability mass concentrates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287718/zero-sum-property-of-the-difference-between-the-data-and-the-mean/287727#287727), it is the outcome that we ["expect on average"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265123/why-is-the-expected-value-named-so), median is the value that divides your data in two halves (50% lies on the right of it, 50% lies on the left), while mode is the "most common" value. Each of those statistics gives you some simple summary of the data.

Comment: Tim there might be a typo in your answer. You defined "mode" twice. The first "mode" was probably meant to be median.

Comment: @Tim From your experience, why are these simple summaries of data important?

Comment: @StatisticallyDead say that you have dataset of 10000 cases by 1000 variables, would you look at each of the 10000x1000 values individually to get a feeling about the data? Summary statistics summarize the data to make understanding it easier.

Comment: @Tim Thank you, I guess I have to keep in mind the big picture of statistics each step of the way as I continue to learn it. Often times we cannot have the entire population in a data set so we have to rely on a mean of a sample to help us make an inference to learn what the mean of the population may be.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is too broad to be answered. But one example would be : assume $A$ is your data matrix,

> If you *center* columns (variables) of $\bf A$, then $\bf A'A$ is the **scatter** (or co-scatter, if to be rigorous) matrix and $\mathbf {A'A}/(n-1)$ is the **covariance** matrix.

Details can be found in

[Is there an intuitive interpretation of $A^TA$ for a data matrix $A$?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22501/is-there-an-intuitive-interpretation-of-ata-for-a-data-matrix-a)

If no centering, such nice property will disappear. A related post here, explains why it matters in the application of PCA

[How does centering make a difference in PCA (for SVD and eigen decomposition)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189822/how-does-centering-make-a-difference-in-pca-for-svd-and-eigen-decomposition)