# Is there a way to calculate peaks of a distribution mathematically?

Tags: distributions, multimodality, shapiro-wilk-test

I’m trying to find some way to mathematically calculate the number of peaks in a distribution. I know there are various tests (such as Shapiro Wilk) that assess whether a distribution is normal, but I’m not aware of any that actually tell you how many peaks are present. Normally, I’d just do this visually, but this is for a program that involves changes of distribution over time. The end goal is to show how the distribution changes (or doesn’t) from a normal distribution to a multimodal distribution over time — including tracking different numbers of peaks, should that happen. So I need to be able to:

1. look beyond just whether the distribution is normal or not and
2. have this happen programmatically, not visually.
   Does such an algorithm exist?

Comment: How do you do it when you do it visually?

Comment: There are a lot of peak-finding algorithms in the topic of signal processing. You could compute densities or probabilities and then try a peak-finding algorithm. One option is [`scipy.signal.find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html).

Comment: If you have a smooth density function, you could also use calculus methods to find local maxima.

Comment: My initial step is to just look at the histogram and count the peaks visually using my own judgment. I’ve thought about how to translate this to something more quantifiable, but I keep stumbling on how to identify where the troughs fall when the number of peaks may change and not every dip is a trough — especially at the extreme ends of a distribution. If it were only ever going to be bimodal or unimodal, that would be fairly easy, but I could wind up with three or four peaks

Comment: Are you asking about *mathematically defined* distribution functions or *empirical distributions* or *estimates of distributions based on data?*  What would be the inputs of the desired algorithm?

Comment: @whuber I’m essentially trying to count the peaks in a histogram from measurements of a population.

Comment: That's a [standard computation.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=identify+peak)  Please explain how your problem differs from the solutions already posted here, such as at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176112.